# how to store the seconds spent on each lesson using ajax, efficient way?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, performance, laravel-4

I am working on the LMS(Laravel,jQuery), where I would like to store **each second** which student spent on the course lesson.

**Eg**: student access the Lesson **Heart beat and Blood flow**, now start the timer for that specific lesson, Student spent **5 Minutes 15 seconds** and change the Lesson to **Blood flow in the Human Body**, now Store the time for the new lesson.

Currently I am doing it by **AJAX**, on every second **AJAX** send the request to the system and it store the time for that specific Lesson.

I believe its not the professional and efficient way to do it like this, because if there are 3000+ user online and each accessed the lesson, then there will be (**3000 students * 60 seconds = 180000**) Ajax calls in single minute.

Kindly guide me for the professional and efficient way.

Thanks